# Бот - напоминалка в Telegram. Проблема с глобальными переменными

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Пишу простенький скрипт, который должен закреплять сообщения в чате телеграмма раз в неделю попеременно меняя текст. Возникает ошибка в if. Хотел проверять недели на четные и нечетные, но почему то возникает ошибка "Unresolved reference 'w' " хотя переменная глобальная

```
import schedule
import time

bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')

w = 1


@bot.message_handler(commands=['pin'])
def command():
    if w % 2 == 0:
        chat_id = 'hardcode_id'
        to_pin = bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Дежурный 1').message_id
        bot.pin_chat_message(chat_id, message_id=to_pin)
        w += 1
    else:
        chat_id = 'hardcode_id'
        to_pin = bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Дежурный 2').message_id
        bot.pin_chat_message(chat_id, message_id=to_pin)
        w += 1


schedule.every().monday.at('10:00').do(command)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: а по факту говоря, выдав свой ответ и проработав ваш код, у вас явно больше ошибок чем связанных в вопросе, начиная с отсутствием параметра на вход в функции типа `message`, отсутствием импорта `telebot`, отсутствием пулинга бота, неправильной реализации счедулов.

Comment: @Acinit  `schedule` - это `скеджьюл` или `шедьюл`, в зависимости от того, на какой стороне Атлантики вы говорите.

Comment: @strawdog не знал кстати, но я язык сломал когда пытался прочесть `скеджьюл`, буду знать, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `global` для вызова глобальных переменных внутри функций

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['pin'])
def command(message):
    global w
    if w % 2 == 0:
        chat_id = 'hardcode_id'
        to_pin = bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Дежурный 1').message_id
        bot.pin_chat_message(chat_id, message_id=to_pin)
        w += 1
    else:
        chat_id = 'hardcode_id'
        to_pin = bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Дежурный 2').message_id
        bot.pin_chat_message(chat_id, message_id=to_pin)
        w += 1
```